# How to set input's value from state and allowing the user to change it?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, forms, input

I have a form in a react app that allows the user to edit something they posted and I want to set the default input's value as the old publication (stored in State) so that they can change it in real life.
For example, the user created a note and then they want to change a word in that, not the whole note.

**Hey, this is my old note** to **Hey, this is my new note**

This is the form, it works perfectly except for the input value.

(the state is set by props that come from another component and it has nothing to do with the problem, I think)

```
import React, {Component} from 'react';
import { connect } from 'react-redux';
import {editNote} from "../actions/noteActions"


class EditNote extends React.Component{
    constructor(props){
        super(props);

        this.onChangeTitle = this.onChangeTitle.bind(this);
        this.onChangeBody = this.onChangeBody.bind(this);
        this.onSubmit = this.onSubmit.bind(this);

        this.state = {
            id: this.props.note[0],
            newNote:{ 
                title : this.props.note[1],
                body : this.props.note[2]
            },
            error : ""
        }
    }

    onChangeTitle(e){
        const newTitle = e.target.value;
        this.setState(prevState => ({
            ...prevState,
            newNote: {
               ...prevState.newNote,
            title: newTitle 
            }
        }))
    }

    onChangeBody(e){
        const newBody = e.target.value;
        this.setState(prevState => ({
            ...prevState,
            newNote: {
               ...prevState.newNote,
            body: newBody 
            }
        }))
    }

    onSubmit(e){
        e.preventDefault();
        this.props.editNote(this.state.id, this.state.newNote);
        this.props.history.push("/");
    }

    render(){
        return(
            <div>
        <h1>Edit your note</h1>
        <form onSubmit={this.onSubmit}>
            <label>Title</label>
            <input onChange={this.onChangeTitle} name="title" type="text" />
            <label>Note</label>
            <input onChange={this.onChangeBody} name="body" type="text" />
            <button>Update changes!</button>
        </form>
        </div>
        )
    }
}

const mapDispatchToProps = (dispatch) => ({
    editNote: (id, updates) => dispatch(editNote(id, updates))
  });
  

export default connect(null, mapDispatchToProps)(EditNote);
```

I can set the input's value with this.state but then it doesn't allow me to change any of it, and I can't find another way to do it.

```
<input onChange={this.onChangeTitle} name="title" type="text" value={this.state.newNote.title}/>
```

Comment: Your code is working fine as it is -https://jsfiddle.net/4howanL2/

Comment: It is working, I was just wondering how I could set the input's value from state and at the same time allow the user to change the text inside the input. When I set the value to be THIS.STATE.NEWNOTE.TITLE it appears but it doesn't let me change it, it's static.

Comment: In the fiddle I posted a link to the input value comes from the state

Comment: You're right! I'm sorry, I didn't see that. My code was fine, I figured out that the problem lied in my set up but I solved it. Thanks!

Comment: Glad you hear you could sort this out! And thanks for letting me know!